SOAP with NodeJS - req.then is not a function
I have an older app that's going through an upgrade process (server hardware/OS, NodeJS + modules, SQL server, etc.).
The application has a 2FA with SOAP. For this I've used this module.
Now I've upgrade to the latest version of the module (1.0.0) and I encountered the following error: req.then is not a function.
According to the documentation not much is changed in terms of API calls so I am pretty sure it is something I missed / didn't notice but I just can't figure it out what it is.
const url = 'https://example.com/wsi/service.php?wsdl';

let args = {
    username: 'username',
    authKey: 'auth_key',
    sender: '',
    recipient: req.user.phone,
    message: '',
    scheduleDate: '',
    validity: '',
    callbackUrl: ''
};

let request_with_defaults = request.defaults({ 'proxy': 'proxy', 'timeout': 5000, 'connection': 'keep-alive' });
let soap_client_options = { 'request': request_with_defaults };

args.message = generateSMSCode(req, codeTime);
args.recipient = phone;

soap.createClient(url, soap_client_options, function(err, client) {
    client.sendSmsAuthKey(args, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(currentDateTime.getCurrentDate() + " - ERROR!");
            console.log(err);
        }

        console.log(currentDateTime.getCurrentDate() + " - Code Sent at " + codeDateTime + "!");

        res.redirect('/auth/validate');
    });
});

So far I've noticed that if I remove the options parameter (soap_client_options), I do get a server error since there is no authentication key but other than that, I can't figure it out.
Is there something wrong with the options parameter?
I appreciate any suggestion.
LE:
function generateSMSCode(req, codeTime) {
    console.log(currentDateTime.getCurrentDate() + " - sendsms.js > generateSMSCode");

    let token = speakeasy.totp({
        secret: JSON.parse(req.user.secretID).base32,
        encoding: 'base32',
    });

    let generatedMessage = token + " SMS MESSAGE";

    return generatedMessage;
}


the error maybe inside the generateSMSCode because there is no req.then in the code you shared

@YuvarajM I've updated the post to include the function. No req.then there either.

so then we have to catch by error stack, did find any links to the files where req.then is used via error stack?

@YuvarajM Nope, not really. This is the only thing I get. And from what I can tell, it seems to be in the SOAP module itself. That's why I am thinking maybe the parameters are wrong since removing them seems to be working (except for the lack of the auth key, that is).
